# Force VSCode CMake Tools extension to use "Unix Makefiles" for the generator

Tags: visual-studio-code

[By default, CMakeTools picks a generator of his choosing](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/configuring.html).

In my system, by default, CMake Tools is picking `Ninja` to be the generator, instead of the desired `Unix Makefiles` (stored in CMakeCache.txt as `CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Ninja`)

Supposedly [you can force CMakeTools' hand when picking the generator by using the `cmake.generator` setting in settings.json](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#conf-cmake-generator)

When doing by hand `cmake -B build` in my system, CMakeCache.txt contains `CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Unix Makefiles`

Thus I set my current settings.json in $workspace/.vscode to

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
    "cmake.generator": "Unix Makefiles",
}
```

but when configuring, it still picks Ninja.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a caching issue somewhere. After restarting VSCode it worked as expected

If you alter the "cmake.generator" entry, delete build folder, and rerun CMake's configuration step

```
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-7 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++-7 -H/home/dario/temp/CMakeToolsTest -B/home/dario/temp/CMakeToolsTest/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

the value after the -G flag does not change accordingly