# Set make as project builder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have created simple Cmake project in Visual Studio Code. As default Cmake extension generates Ninja build system files. How to switch build system from Ninja to Make?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities to solve it:

- Either you resolve by installing a relatively new [Makefile tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) extension in your Visual Studio Code.
- Or may be you need to resolve [caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155296/force-vscode-cmake-tools-extension-to-use-unix-makefiles-for-the-generator).

Comment: my default CMake generated Make files so no new extension needed,

Comment: so you want to change the build system but not delete the build directory, you expect that to work, CMake writes a lot of settings stuff in the build directory